# Select data by Spark from Cassandra using primary key

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Spark-Cassandra connector for reading data from Cassandra. I have next table in C*:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (key uuid PRIMARY KEY, value text);
```

I want to get list of `my_table` records by list of their keys. I wrote next code:

```
sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table")
   .select("value") 
   .where("key in ?", listOfKeys).collect()
```

In logs I saw next info:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT
>   "values" FROM "my_keyspace"."my_table" WHERE token("key") > ? AND
>   token("key") <= ? AND key in ?   ALLOW FILTERING: key cannot be
>   restricted by more than one relation if it includes a IN

I found next reported bug with won't fix status in C* JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6151

How can I read data from C* using spark-cassandra connector by primary key?

Cassandra v. 2.1.9
Spark v. 1.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use joinWithCassandraTable method for this purpose.

Something like this:

```
val keys = sc.parallelize(listOfKeys)
val rowsRDD = keys.map(Tuple1(_))
    .repartitionByCassandraReplica("my_keyspace","my_table")
    .joinWithCassandraTable("my_keyspace","my_table")
```

You can find more about reading from C* in the connector documentation [there](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md).

Keep in mind that using IN in the WHERE clause is usually not recommended as described [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectIN.).